# const variable can be redeclared inside while loop even though it should be constant

Tags: javascript, variables, while-loop, scope, constants

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and have run across a situation I don't quite understand:
Have a look at this code:

```js
let i = 0;
while (i < 4) {
  const test = i;
  console.log(test);
  i++;
}
```

As a result the console would print me out something like this:

0,
1,
2,
3 .
I thought that in opposition to the var keyword, a variable with the const keyword can't be re declared, but still every time the loop restarts the test variable is declared again (not only updated but declared completely new).
How is that possible? I assume it has something to do with the execution context or the scope, and actually my test variable should be scoped to the block (while-loop), but it can somehow still be reassigned every time through the loop.

Comment: In opposition to the `var` keyword, a variable declared with `const` will only be scoped to the wrapping code block (curly braces). So, here a brand new `test` variable is created on every iteration. It is never altered, and each _iteration_ has no knowledge of a previously created `test` variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const` prevents variables from being *reassigned*, eg

```
const test = i;
test = 10; // this would not be allowed
```

It does not prevent variables from being re-declared when the block runs again, otherwise it'd be pretty impossible to do anything:

```js
let i = 0;
function foo() {
  const test = i;
  console.log(test);
  i++;
};

foo();
foo(); // nothing wrong with running a function a second time
```

A given block can be run as many times as the script-writer directs it to. The only restriction with `const` is that *inside a given invocation of a block*, a `const` can't be reassigned.

`const` and `let` similarly can't be re-declared *in a given invocation of a block*, eg:

```
const test = i;
const test = 10; // re-declaration in the same block; forbidden
```

But there's nothing wrong with running the *whole block* again and creating another binding for a variable declared once inside the block, like in the above snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much for that awesome explanation. Much appreciated!